# How to find images src with https within it using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to get all image src's that contain https:// with BeautifulSoup

```
image_list = []
url = 'www.example.com'
r = requests.get(url)
soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_list.append(link.get('src'))

for link in image_list:
    if 'https' not in link:
        image_list.remove(link)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't delete values from a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: im trying to get all image src links from a webpage that contain "https://" at the start of it.

Comment: @lolz That's a statement, not a question. Next time describe what error or problems you are facing.

Comment: You need web crawler which could be best info in this link: [link] (http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `src` starts with `https`, then filter it, eg:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
image_list=[]
div_test="""
<html>
    <div id="d1">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <img src="http://test1.com/1.jpg"></img>
    <div id="d2">
        Text 2
        <a href="http://my.url/">a url</a>
        Text 2 continue
    </div>
    <img src="https://test2.com/2.jpg"></img>

    <div id="d3">
        Text 3
    </div>
    <img src="https://test3.com/3.jpg"></img>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    src = link.get('src')
    if src.startswith("https"): #check src starts with https
        image_list.append(src)
print(image_list)
```

`image_list` will be only for `https`:

```
[u'https://test2.com/2.jpg', u'https://test3.com/3.jpg']
```